# Can't center Slick Carousel on page

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm using the Slick Carousel (slick.js) but am having trouble horizontally centering the carousel on the page.

HTML:

```
<!-- logo slider -->

<section id="customer-carousel" class="slider responsive container m-5">
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/eth_zuerich_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="/images/customers/kbsi_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/max-planck-institute-goettingen.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/nc_state_university_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/osaka_university_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/phoenixnmr_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/ruhr_universitaet_bochum_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/synex_medical_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/technical_university_of_brno_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/tu_ilmenau_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/tu_kaiserslautern_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/ucsb_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/UMD_logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/customers/unh-logo.png" class="customer-slide">
  </div>
</section>


<!-- /logo slider -->
```

CSS:

```
#customer-carousel {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.customer-slide {
    width: 8rem;
    max-height: 10rem; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // Preloader js    
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(100);
  });
  
  // Accordions
  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.ti-angle-right').removeClass('ti-angle-right').addClass('ti-angle-down');
  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.ti-angle-down').removeClass('ti-angle-down').addClass('ti-angle-right');
  });

  
    //slider
    $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false
    });

})(jQuery);
```

The page is staged here & the carousel is right on the home page (customer logos):
http://bridge12-staging.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

Really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class "m-5" on the slider that's setting the margins to 3rem!important.  Removing that class seems to fix the horizontal centering.  If that class is needed, you could override the margins in your CSS by ID:

```
#customer-carousel {
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-right: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that did the trick!